# How to scrape text from html using Selenium or Beautiful Soup

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

here is the html

```
<div data-v-026c45df="" class="col text-undefined">$682.0</div>
```

I need the '$682.0'. I have tried :

```
start_aum = driver.find_element_by_class_name('col text-undefined').get_attribute

print(start_aum)
```

and

```
start_aum = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('col text-undefined').get_attribute

print(start_aum)
```

both return

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".col text-undefined"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.190)
```

I am open to using beautiful soup or selenium but I can't seem to understand why I am having problems selecting the element.

Answer (score 1):

There might some issue with the element visibility etc., but I can't see the whole code, so I'll react to only what's in your question:

- `get_attribute` is a method, you are not calling it, you'd need something like `get_attribute("class")`
- `$682.0` is not an attribute, it's text, you need to get it with `.text`, e.g. `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.col.text-undefined').text`
- in `find_element_by_css_selector('col text-undefined')` there's an incorrect selector, the correct one would be `.col.text-undefined`

Comment: to be able to know if it is an issue with element visibility do you need to see the html, or my script?

Comment: I'd fix these things first, then study a bit along these topics https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/10401931 and then possibly change the script further.

Comment: After doing some research I am trying to utilize this line of code from the link you attached for me. `check_box = WebDriverWait(Browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tableview-3687-record-2128"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div')))
check_box.click()` but I am getting the error that 'By' is not defined. I found the dependencies for the other bit in that line of code but I'm not sure what I need in order to use the 'By' part

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By` You also have one extra pair of brackets there, although Python should not complain in this situation.

Comment: also worth noting that `find_element_by_class_name()` can't take multiple classes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771604/selenium-compound-class-names-not-permitted

Answer (score 0):

Your locator is wrong, use

```
   start_aum = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="col text-undefined"]').Text

   print(start_aum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".col.text-undefined").text
```

Comment: What would be the difference between this and pavel's answer?

Comment: Please add some explanation to the answer that might be helpful.

Comment: Pavels answer is correct, no difference